# How do I install jSweet?

Tags: javascript, java, ssl, installation

I'm trying to install jSweet to convert java to javascript code. 
Instructions on the following page: http://www.jsweet.org/getting-started/#Getting_started

tell me that after installing the necessary files I should use the following in a Command Prompt:

git clone https://github.com/cincheo/jsweet-quickstart.git

That produces:
Cloning into 'jsweet-examples'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/cincheo/jsweet-examples.git/': error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

How should I resolve the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+SSL+routines%3ASSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO%3Atlsv1+alert+protocol+version

Answer (score 0):

The most common solution was to update git to the latest version.  As of now, the latest version is 2.20.1.  You can check what version you have using `git --version` in terminal or the command prompt.

[HERE](https://git-scm.com/downloads) is a link to the git downloads page if you need to update git.

Answer (score 0):

Download the repository content directly and add the project into eclipse (assuming you use eclipse) by loading the maven project from It's pom-file.